# Apex class not visible for selection inside flow as an Apex Defined datatype

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

In the below code why am I not able to select the OuterClass class as an Apex defined data type inside of the flow. As mentioned in the docs the members of the OuterClass has @AuraEnabled annotation and it is a class in its own file.

```
public class OuterClass {
    @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required = true)
    public List<InnerClass> innerClassList;

        public OuterClass() {}
    
        public class InnerClass {
            public Integer var1;
            public String var2;
        
            public InnerClass() {
                this.var1= 1;
    
            }
        }  
    }
```

UPDATE as per Adrians Comments -

```
global class OuterClass {
    @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required = true)
    public List<InnerClass> innerClassList;

        public OuterClass() {}
    
        global class InnerClass {
            @AuraEnabled 
            @InvocableVariable
            public Integer var1;

            @AuraEnabled 
            @InvocableVariable
            public String var2;
        
            public InnerClass() {
                this.var1= 1;
    
            }
        }  
    }
```

Comment: did you try making InnerClass a top-level class (its own .cls file)?

Comment: @cropredy yes I did. That way it works and the class is visible inside the flow. I was trying to make the code look cleaner by having both classes in one class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner classes inside of apex types are not supported per the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.flow_considerations_apex_data_type.htm&language=en_US).

> Inner classes are not supported

You can and will commonly use inner classes as the parameter and results to the invocable class itself

```
  public static Result[] doMyInvocable(Request[] requests) {...}
```

where `Result` and `Request` are inner classes.  But if those classes have inner types, said types must be defined as Top level classes in their own files with `AuraEnabled` annotations

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to annotate all parameters as `@invocableVariable`.

```
public class OuterClass {
    @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required = true)
    public List<InnerClass> innerClassList;
    public OuterClass() {}

    public class InnerClass {
        @InvocableVariable // missing
        public Integer var1;
        @InvocableVariable // missing
        public String var2;
    
        public InnerClass() {
            this.var1= 1;

        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I tried that already, still not showing up inside of the flow.

Comment: You _might_ need to also remove `@AuraEnabled`; I'm not sure if they are compatible.

Comment: On this link it says @AuraEnabled annotation is required for the class to be available in the flow https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_apex_data_type.htm&type=5. I only need the members of the OuterClass class to be visible inisde of the flow.

Comment: If `InnerClass` is a parameter, you definitely need its attributes to be visible for it to have any meaning. I really doubt it is the case, but [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_extend_apex_type_action.htm&type=5) does use the global access modifier...

Comment: I have put an update to the original post putting in the changes you mentioned, still I am not able to make the class visible in the flow. I have the InnerClass variables visible .

Comment: Did you check if upgrading the access modifier to `global` makes visible what you need?

Comment: Yes I did, still it doesn't make the class visible inside the flow. I have added the latest code to the original post.

Comment: Your post only has `OurtClass` as `global`...

Comment: Sorry, it was tried with the inner class as global as well, still no luck.